Children's ish book about a crash landed spaceship, only (some of the) children survive, something about a mining revolt?
I read this in the 90s but it was already old then I think. The main character is a girl. Her parents die on impact or something on the planet. She describes them as splats on the wall or something like that. When she wakes up she very specifically mentions that her teeth are fuzzy. I remember that word vividly.
She wakes up in some kind of sleep chamber. She isn't surprised to be there, like she knew that the travel required this kind of sleep.
I believe the story revolved around a mining colony, and how the workers there were not treated well. It gave me Enemy Mine vibes once I saw that movie, but the main character was definitely female and young.
